# Difference in buying two 1x8GB RAM separately and buying a 2x8GB RAM kit

Tags: memory

Is there any difference in buying two 1x8GB RAM and a 2x8GB RAM kit? Other than the price.

Comment: If you buy 2, you can run in dual-channel mode. (If your MB supports it)

Comment: That's not answering the question. I'm asking the difference between two individual 1x8GB sticks and the two sticks that comes in the 2x8GB RAM kit.

Comment: @PulitzLertamornthep - There isn't a difference.  They are the same part, the only difference is the packaging, and the fact one part number comes with 2 modules and the other comes with 1 module.  I have answered this question before, I just can't find, my answer.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/768448/what-is-todays-memory-quad-channel/768456#768456) answer explains the difference between memory kits with 4 modules instead of 2 which applies to this question.  [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1413982/should-i-expect-adding-more-ram-of-the-same-model-to-lead-to-worse-benchmarks/1414006#1414006) answer indicates there is no difference between a 32 GB kit and a 128 GB kit of the same memory module.  I am treating that as the duplicate candiate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real difference is that in almost all cases, the memory modules in a given pack (be it a pair, three, four, six, eight, or some other number) will have been assembled at about the same time using components that were themselves produced at approximately the same time as each other, and occasionally they will have been tested as a set instead of just individually.

This has the potential to matter only in certain very specific cases that probably don't apply to you:

- It makes life easier for enterprise IT departments.  Same date of manufacture almost always translates to roughly the same life expectancy for the parts, as well as having equivalent MTBF (mean time between failures).  This makes hardware life-cycle planning much easier.
- It gives the potential for better stability when doing really aggressive overclocking.  Essentially, chips built at different times may have smal variance in the exact timings, which can hurt stability when used in situations that require high precision for those timings (such as aggressive overclocking).